# Do we need to restrict the depencencies in .NET Core libraries?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, .net-core

I have a library written in full .NET and I am porting it to .NET Core. I intend to make it target the .netstandard1.1 (in order to be also compatible with .NET45).

When I create the project with visual studio, it automatically depends on the NETStandard.Library nuget package.

My library only needs two packages:

- System.Runtime
- System.Runtime.InteropServices

Two questions :

1. Do I need to restrict my project dependencies to only these two packages? Rephrased: may be nuget (or visual studio or another magic stuff) manage to restrict on its own to only the needed packages and not the full NETStandard.Library?
2. If the answer to the first question is no, is it a good idea to perform that restriction?

Thanks in advance.
(Sorry for my english, I am not a native speaker)

Comment: You shouldn't be sorry. Your English is quite fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some aspects in your question...

1. The `netstandard1.1` framework choice will limit your available API surface in the editor (here VS Code) to what is available that version. Just tested with `File.OpenRead` on VS Code for `netstandard1.1` (not available) and `netstandard1.6` (available).
2. The `NETStandard.Library` dependency (version 1.6 is good for both cases) is a package dependency. Once the assembly is compiled, the assembly itself will declare external assemblies (aka referenced assemblies) which were actually used (e.g. System.Runtime and System.Linq) and not all assemblies found in the `NETStandard.Library` meta package.

As long as you are not packaging it up for NuGet, assembly reference restrictions are anyway done for you. NuGet packaging however would refer to the `NETStandard.Library` package

If you use NuGet and that reduction is important to you, I guess the correct term is NuGet dependency trimming, a manual process explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/reducing-dependencies) (short version: copy all references from the meta package and remove all you do not use).

Comment: Indeed my library will be available through NuGet, that's why I wanted to "trim" (thanks for the term ^^) the useless dependencies. But it is good to know it is not necessary when using project referencing. About the trim process, Visual Studio is now able to find the required NuGet dependencies from the code. So when the time come to trim your dependencies, just remove the `NETStandard.Library` and use the `Show potential fix` where you library does not compile.

Comment: A small hint from the recent updates: use netstandard1.4 at maximum. 1.5 and 1.6 will break towards 2.0

Answer (score 1):

1. I am not sure if it's a VS bug, however seems like VS doesn't like building a library and not having a `NETStandard.Library` package included :) So, no.
2. Unless you use Visual Studio Code or Notepad etc. this will slow down your development, since VS will prevent you from building the project etc. So, no again.

The bottom line. 
Premature optimization might cause more issues than benefit. Port your library first, and only then check if you need to optimize it.

Comment: About your 1st point, I do not have any trouble with building my library without `NETStandard.Library`. Is it a known issue or did you experienced it recently? I am using `Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3` with the `.NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2`. Perhaps there is Something broken with your set up?

Comment: Seems like it was just temporary glitch in VS... Compiles properly now.